# Getting undefined offset in my PHP For loop

Tags: php, arrays

These are the errors I'm getting

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp64\www\searches.php on line 35
>   Call Stack
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp64\www\searches.php on line 35
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp64\www\searches.php on line 42

Line 35 is  `$totalSum = $totalSum + $amYearNumbers[1][$x];`

This is part of the whole for loop

```
preg_match_all('/(\d)\s<span>year/', $amItemYEAR, $amYearNumbers);
print_r($amYearNumbers);
if ($amYearNumbers) {
    $amYearNumbersLength = count($amYearNumbers);
    $totalSum = 0;
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $amYearNumbersLength ; $x++) {
        $totalSum = $totalSum + $amYearNumbers[1][$x];
    }
}
```

`print_r($amYearNumbers);` returns

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 8 year ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) )

I'm sure what the error is exactly, I just want to add up all the numbers that are given back

Comment: Why not use the count in the for loop? Not that it should solve the problem but still? `for ($x = 0; $x <= count($amYearNumbers); $x++) {`

Comment: not all of your data array appears to be numeric, `8 year` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

```
if (count($amYearNumbers)) {
    $amYearNumbersLength = count($amYearNumbers[0]);
    $totalSum = 0;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $amYearNumbersLength ; $x++) {
        $totalSum = $totalSum + $amYearNumbers[0][$x];
    }
}
```

Comment: try with change `for ($x = 0; $x < $amYearNumbersLength ; $x++) {`

Comment: It works! But why is it `$totalSum = $totalSum + $amYearNumbers[0][$x];` and not `$totalSum = $totalSum + $amYearNumbers[1][$x];`

Comment: because here `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 8 year ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 8 ) )`  1st position with `0` index which is $amYearNumbers[0] is fixed not $amYearNumbers[1]

Comment: But like, I don't want the ones that say 8 year, I just want the number 8

Comment: You can check by either http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: those covers in loop with value of `$x`, so only the first array is fixed and inside that array is dynamic in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($amYearNumbers) {
    $amYearNumbersLength = count($amYearNumbers);
    $totalSum = 0;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $amYearNumbersLength ; $x++) {
        $totalSum += $amYearNumbers[$x][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay cool cool. I get one error still tho `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 35`

Comment: `echo $amYearNumbers[1][0]." -- <br>";` does it show an error?

Answer (score 0):

You do not count the same as you loop.

```
count($amYearNumbers); =2??
// then your loop goes in $amyearnumbers[1] which is 1

//So either do: 
For ($x = 0; $x <= count($amYearNumbers[1]); $x++) {
Or keep the count above as you do now but do:
$amYearNumbersLength = count($amYearNumbers[1]);
```